# How to Execute All TestSuite in Robot Framework Using a Single File

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to Robot framework. I was wrote many suites in different different foldar and want to execute them all, just by executing single file like we do in Java TestNG using xml file. Is There a way, Please help me. My Framework structure is like that:

```
Dir1
  TestSuite1
  TestSuite2
Dir2
  TestSuite1
  TestSuite1
```

I want to execute all testcases in all Testsuite.
Thank You

Comment: If you multiple directories then go for root project directory. Give root directory as argument. Robot framework has capabilities to identify and run your test cases.

Comment: Hi Jeet I already mentioned that I have no idea and that's why I am asking this. Instead of giving -ve comment it will be nice to give proper answer

Comment: I gave proper answer only, not -ve.

Answer (score 5):

you can execute it by simple command line

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-test-cases

```
robot /path/to/your_tests
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume below is your project structure,

```
Dir0(main project directory(root directory for project) where your have all the files)
    Dir1
       TestSuit1
       TestSuit2
    Dir2
       TestSuit1
       TestSuit2
    Dir3
       Dir4
         TestSuit1
         TestSuit2
       TestSuit3
```

Then you can execute test cases using below command

```
robot dir0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. You can run it via:

   ```
   robot <parent_directory_containing_Dir1_and_Dir2>
   ```
2. You can write python script that will iterate and add all your individual robot file.